# JavaScript animation is never executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty simple sliding animation, but when I click the `tallarrowsright` div, nothing happens. Am I looking over something obvious?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var all = 3;
    var current = 1;

    $(".tallarrowsright").click(function(){
        if(current<all){
            $(".slideme").animate({left:"-=1000"},500)
            current = current+1   
        }
    })
```

Comment: I edited this to be properly formatted and noticed you were missing the closing bracket of your ready callback. Was that a copy paste error or did you actually omit it?

Comment: Side note: while you cannot comment on other user's posts, you can comment on your own. So if you need to reply, you may do so here in the comments.

Comment: Put your html code here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not animation problem, but css issue. Try to add `position:relative` to .slideme

[working code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqGRM41zgeSMGMnoRPx4)

just click "Basic plunk!" :)

Answer (score -1):

Fix: (Assuming `$(".tallarrowsright")` exists on `document.ready`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var all = 3;
    var current = 1;
    $(".tallarrowsright").click(function(){
        if(current < all){
            $(".slideme").animate({
                left:"-=1000"}, 500, function(){
                     // Animation complete.
                    current = current + 1;
                    console.log(current);
                });
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: I corrected all your syntax errors. If `.tallarrowsright` exists on document ready the function should execute. Check if you have the class name right, it should be the same as the one you use in the jQuery selector.